# First challenger loses but team win means elimination?

Tags: pokemon-go

I want to ask, at the Pokemon Go gym there are 3 defenders and I'm the first challenger (the first fighter) on the line-up.

If our gym get attacked I lost, but my team win (the rest fight), will I be eliminated from the gym?

This is my first experience defending gym ever, I put 1124 combat power Scyther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the gym prestige goes down one level the lowest level Pokemon will be kicked out. So in your case it will depend on the gym level and how much prestige your gym has lost. Anyhow yours will be the first to be kicked out eventually if you have the lowest one in there.

Comment: So If I lost the fight, but my two friends win, I get kicked out from the Gym and my 2 friends stay there?

Comment: Only if the gym went down a full prestige level. Let's say your gym has 7000 prestige with 3 pokemon defending it (one is yours). Someone attacks it and wins from your pokemon but loses against the other ones. The gym goes down by 1000 prestige points to 6000. This means your Pokemon will still be there. If it drops below 6000 yours will be the first to be removed.